# Return exit code from command line argument in batch file

Tags: command-line, batch-file, exit-code

What I'm looking to do is to report the exit code of a command line argument and was wondering if this is possible..

For example:

```
myProgram.exe aThirdPartyProgram.exe
```

and I want to get hold of the exit code of `aThirdPartyProgram` that is used within the `myProgram`. The reason for doing this is to create a batch file that can be used to test multiple pieces of software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless `myProgram.exe` outputs or returns anything that has to do with the exit code of `aThirdPartyProgram.exe`, then no, there isn't a way. From your batch file `aThirdPartyProgram.exe` is just an argument to `myProgram.exe`; there is no indication whatsoever that it's a program at all that is going to be executed. Furthermore, `myProgram.exe` runs the program, not your batch, so if it doesn't tell you its exit code, then you're out of luck.

If `myProgram` just passes on the exit code of `aThirdPartyProgram` you can use the pseudo-variable `%ERRORLEVEL%` which contains the exit code of the last command.

Comment: Thanks for your fast response Joey, I will check if it is at all possible to grab the return code in myProgram, I'd imagine it does, or if not it certainly has the capability to do so, I'd imagine what your suggesting is to pass down the error code as the error code for myProgram (or something useful etc!)

Comment: @Sayse type in `cmd.exe` following command `if /?` and read about `ERRORLEVEL`